# 'hook_entity_operation_alter', but for users

Tags: 8, hooks

I'd like to customise the Operations dropdowns on */admin/people*

The [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_operation_alter/8.6.x) for **hook_entity_operation_alter()** says the second parameter should be:

*\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity:*

However when I do:

```
function mymodule_entity_operation_alter(array &$operations, EntityInterface $entity) {
    kint( $entity );
}
```

I get:

> Argument 2 passed to mymodule_entity_operation_alter() must be an instance of EntityInterface, instance of Drupal\user\Entity\User given

Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: You are missing use statement in mymodule.module file. This can be only case that this is not working.

Comment: William, please give crdit to @drupality in your own answer ...

Answer (score 2):

*mymodule.module* also needs:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
```

Credits to [drupality](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1178/drupality), who first mentioned this in a comment below my question